# SAPUI5 OData Select

Tags: odata, sapui5, hana-xs

currently i am facing issues with my xsodata service. It is created based on HANA calculation view. It has one collection with about 40 properties.
I want to use filters and the select system query.

```
        var aFilter = [new sap.ui.model.Filter("YEAR", "EQ", "2016"),
                       new sap.ui.model.Filter("MONTH", "EQ", "12")];
        oModelBstVertraege.read("/Collection", {
            "urlParameters": {"$select": "YEAR,MONTH"},
            "filters": aFilter,
            "success": (oData, response) => {
                console.log(oData);
                }
        });
```

I expected this code snippet to just return the entries for the properties YEAR and MONTH where YEAR equals 2016 and MONTH equals 12. I expect about 7500 entries but only receive one.
also when i comment out the "filters" I only receive one entry.

Has anybody suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some more info please: how is your $metadata look like for that entity type, what are the property data types? What are the property values of the returning record?

Comment: It is an OData service based on HANA Calculation View. The property data types are int32. 
I think the service itself doesn't work hjow it should. I will figure it out and post an answer if i solve the problem.
Thanks so far.

Comment: By now i think the service works as it should be. It is the logic of the calculation view the service is based on. The result is an OData service which works different than the OData specification tells.